# 16.04 doesn't boot after instalation, froze by restart button, please help

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation

I have the problem that after the instalation of **16.04** on my laptop (**Gigabyte P57WV7-DE022T**) the system **doesn't boot** :/

Also at the end of the installation when it says ,,restart the system to complete the instalation'' and I press the ,,restart'' button it **freezes** and nothing works anymore.
Then I have to force the shutdown with the powerbutton :/

The Version **17.10** has the **same problem** on my laptop.

For the installation I **used a usb** stick.

On my **desctop** and on **virtuelbox** on the same laptop, ubuntu **works fine** somehow :)
**Windosw** is also still working good :)

I tried everything I know, can someone please help? :/

I have one Image of how far ubuntu boots:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this looks like a BIOS bug.  You might try updating your system BIOS from Windows side to make sure.

Comment: thank you for the answere ^^ i will try it at the weekend :)